# Как мне из Observable<io.rxjava> сохранить данные в List<>?

Tags: java, android, rxjava2

Есть метод, который получает данные из json и создает `Observable<>`, из него мне нужно получить данные и сохранить в `List<>`:

```
@NonNull
public Observable<List<BaseProducts>> getProducts(){
    return bankApi.getProductsObservable()
            //здесь получаю result
            .map(productResponseApiResponse -> productResponseApiResponse.getResult())
            //здесь конвертирую result в готовые типы (DTO)
            .map(response -> converter.convert(response))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Дальше мне нужно отфильтровать данные и передать в List<>

```
@NonNull
private Observable<List<BaseProducts>> getActive(){
    return getProducts()
            .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
            .filter(products -> !products.getStatus().equals(ACTIVE_PRODUCTS))
            .toList()
            .toObservable();
}
```

Происходит фильтрация, как теперь мне отфильтрованный поток сохранить в List<>?

Например, если сохранить в `List<>`

```
@NonNull
public List<BaseProducts> getActiveProducts(){
    List<BaseProducts> activeProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    getProducts()
            .subscribe(products -> activeProducts.addAll(products));
    return activeProducts;
}
```

Но через `debugger` показывает, что `activeProducts = null`, когда `products` хранит в себе данные

```
@Inject
public ProductsItemBuilderImpl(@NonNull ProductsRepository repository) {
    this.baseProducts = repository.getActiveProducts();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public List<BaseProductsItem> build() {
    buildDeposits(baseProducts);
    buildCredits(baseProducts);
    buildDebitCards(baseProducts);
    buildCreditCards(baseProducts);
    return baseProductsItems;
}
```

Здесь вызываю это самый List

Comment: `.subscribe()` ?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Поподробней пожалуйста, с rxjava большие недопонимания, как именно его использовать?

Comment: Вы ознакомились с операторами, которые можно использовать, но не знаете как непосредственно обрабатывать поток данных? Я спрашиваю без сарказма, просто не пойму, на каком уровне вы находитесь и в чём конкретно вопрос.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin В этом и вопрос, последний метод, я вроде бы передаю данные, сохраняю в List, но или не сохраняет, или я не правильно делаю

Comment: Что конкретно вы делаете? Где вызываете эти методы? Как обрабатываете подписку?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin правил свой вопрос, не думаю, что он как то поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка кроется здесь:

```
List<BaseProducts> activeProducts = new ArrayList<>();
getProducts()
    .subscribe(products -> activeProducts.addAll(products));
return activeProducts;
```

Нельзя просто так взять, и вернуть значение синхронно из подписки. Точнее, делать этого совсем не стоит. `RxJava` создавали для реализации реактивного, асинхронного подхода.

Если более кратко — на момент выполнения строчки `return activeProducts` список будет ещё пуст, так как переход к ней произойдет сразу после предыдущей строчки, без ожидания выполнения переданных вами лямбд.

Слишком подробно всё расписывать не вижу смысла — про асинхронное программирование (даже в рамках `Java` и `RxJava`) исписано пол интернета, поищите статей на эту тему. На вашу ошибку я указал, обратите внимание. Вы ознакомились с операторами `RxJava` и начали с ней работать, но не знаете как этим пользоваться.

Не пытайтесь хранить полученные откуда-то данные у себя в полях, используйте цепочки методов. Получили данные — вызвали метод, который их сможет обработать, передали туда эти данные. Там поместили их куда-нибудь в список в адаптере, отобразили на UI, сохранили в базу и так далее. Переосмыслите подход — не храните данные в поле, а потом откуда-то вызывайте их, а сразу при получении вызывайте получателя (слушателя, подписчика), который сможет эти данные обработать.

Comment: Обычно так и делаю, но в данном случае не получается реализовать данный подход

Comment: @АнтонЛялин пересмотрите логику, лучше поменять её, чем пытаться синхронно получить данные через `RxJava`.